# Percentage values after matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, apply, matrix-multiplication

By matrix multiplication I get the following matrix, which, let's say, shows how many customers who purchased product A, sooner or later, also purchased product B, product C and so on. Obviously, the diagonal values represent 100% of all purchases of a particular product. I'm looking for a way of converting all the values to percentage values. Any ideas? I did have a look at apply(), but didn't find a way to implement the diagonal values.

```
> # Create a matrix with zeros and ones
> r <- 500
> c <- 10
> t1 <- matrix(rbinom(r*c,1,0.5),r,c)
> colnames(t1) <- letters[1:10]
> head(t1)
     a b c d e f g h i j
[1,] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
[2,] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
[3,] 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
[4,] 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
[5,] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
[6,] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
> # Matrix multiplication
> t2 <- t(t1)%*%t1
> t2
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
a 242 130 121 114 133 117 119 126 123 112
b 130 248 121 115 128 121 113 127 114 119
c 121 121 236 108 115 117 115 117 112 117
d 114 115 108 228 116 117 114 110 118  99
e 133 128 115 116 258 129 124 132 122 130
f 117 121 117 117 129 251 123 115 128 125
g 119 113 115 114 124 123 245 128 130 116
h 126 127 117 110 132 115 128 248 123 113
i 123 114 112 118 122 128 130 123 251 116
j 112 119 117  99 130 125 116 113 116 246
```

Comment: If you look at `(a,b)=130`, what is the reference value to which the percentage is calculated?

Comment: It'd be a, a. Bridgeburners' answer solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t3 <- apply(t2, 2, function(v) v/max(v))
```

or

```
for (i in 1:ncol(t2)) t2[,i] <- t2[,i]/t2[i,i]
```

I'm assuming you want the asymmetric matrix, i.e. percentage of people who purchased product X who also purchased product Y (which is different from percentage of people who purchased product Y who also purchased product X).